# What does increment as the second parameter of BsonTimestamp constructor in Mongodb mean?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Checking the documentation of mongodb [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) . It says the second parameter of BsonTimestamp is

> the second 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second

Which I did not understand very well.

Could someone please help me to understand by explaining in more detail what does it mean?

Comment: The second parameter is to specify the fractional component from millis to nano seconds.

Comment: Ohh ok I understand now. Thank you @Veeram

Comment: @Veeram where did you get the idea that the increment is millis or nanos? And what would determine if it has to be read as millis or nanos? besides 2^31 is > 2x10^9 so an integer can exceed the number of nanoseconds in a single second

Answer (score 1):

from "the second 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second" I understand it is a ordinal used to distinguish events happening within the same second. Not necessarely representing any time unit o time.

Edit: I've verified the source code of the Java version of the ObjectId class and the inc is a simple counter in the range 0x0 - 0x00ffffff.
Being an internal representation one should not reason on it.

Comment: Interesting! So I see the increment is a parameter to the Driver API , in that sense I dont understand how the user could define an increment what would be the meaning to it? Shouldn't the increment be just an internal core concept which the mongodb server does it automatically?

Comment: Sorry I messed between the two classes BsonTimestamp and ObjectId that both use the same concept of a timestamp and an increment. Still it is true that the increment is just a number provided to distinguish events in the same second "getInc(): @return an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second". So I guess that you could simply put 0 all the times you have events in different seconds, or use a counter to distinguish when you generate more events in a second.